# How to get a circles path in a 3D space when only the points and the distance is given?

Tags: java, math, geometry

I've been trying to get all possible coordinate for a circle in a 3 dimensional space. If only 2 points values given as [x1,y1,z1] and [x2,y2,z2] and the distance from each point is r1 and r2, How can i get the path?

[image]

I used

```
   int radius =100;
   for(int x= -radius; x<=radius; x++ ){
        int sliceDistance = (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(x, 2)));
        for(int y= -sliceDistance; y<=sliceDistance; y++){
            int z = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius,2)-Math.pow(y,2)-Math.pow(x,2)));
            System.out.println(""+x+":"+y+":"+z);
            if(z!=0){
               System.out.println(""+x+":"+y+":"+(-z));
            }
        }
    }
```

to get all the possible values for a sphere in a 3D space given the radius.But have no idea how to get the circle in a 3D space.

Comment: Apply a transformation to move the circle to `z==0`.  Simple trigonometry will enable you to solve the triangle of which `r1` is the hypotenuse, the equation of the circle falls out.  Transform everything back to the original coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This circle is the set S of all 3D points (x,y,z) which satisfy the
equations of both spheres. The equations of the 2 spheres are known:

`(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 + (z-z1)^2 = r1 ^ 2`
`(x-x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 + (z-z2)^2 = r2 ^ 2`

So you have to somehow "solve" this system of 2 equations i.e.
find somehow all (x,y,z) satisfying both equations.

Google for "intersection of two spheres" to start with.

This looks quite good: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128171355/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/64311.html)